# How to exclude tax from custom fee line for the order created via REST API, WooCommmerce

Tags: rest, woocommerce, fee

I have created a website which is using WooCommerce REST API. I was able to create the order successfully and sales taxes for each product item is automatically get calculated as well. But there is custom fee which we are adding for each order named as 'Handling and Insurance Charges'. But the tax rate is getting automatically get added to that fee item which we don't need. Is there a way to exclude tax calculation for the custom fee line.

[image: Here is the tax fee line row. We need the $0.47 tax to be removed]

I have tried some code which looks like

```
$feelines[]=array("name"=>"Handling & Insurance Charges","taxable"=>false,"total"=>$handling_amount);
```

I need a solution for the above said issue.